# Error: Route.put() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] - What is this error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, router

I have no idea why I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Users\yurit\Desktop\EcommcereAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.put() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as put] (C:\Users\yurit\Desktop\EcommcereAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
    at Function.proto.<computed> [as put] (C:\Users\yurit\Desktop\EcommcereAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:510:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yurit\Desktop\EcommcereAPI\routes\user.js:7:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yurit\Desktop\EcommcereAPI\index.js:5:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I thought it was a problem with the node_modules file so I deleted and re-installed it. That didn't work. Here are my other files that may contain the problem

user.js: I think it's here in the user.js file, but ill post the other 2 associated with is file just incase

```
const { verifyToken, verifyTokenAndAuthorization } = require("./verifyToken");

const router = require("express").Router();

//UPDATE
router.put("/:id", verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.password) {
      req.body.password = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
        req.body.password,
        process.env.PASS_SEC
      ).toString();
    }
  
    try {
      const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,

        {
          $set: req.body,
        },
        { new: true }
      );
      res.status(200).json(updatedUser);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });


module.exports = router;
```

verifyToken.js:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.token;
    if (authHeader){
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SEC, (err,user) => {
            if(err) res.status(403).json("Token is not valid!");
            req.user = user;
            next();
        })
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json("You are not authenticated");
    }

    const verifyTokenAndAuthorization = (req, res, next) => {
      verifyToken(req, res, () => {
        if (req.user.id === req.params.id || req.user.isAdmin){
            next();
        } else {
          rez.status(403).json("You are not all to do that!");
        }
      })
    }

    module.exports = { verifyToken, verifyTokenAndAuthorization};
}
```

auth.js:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req,res) => {
    const newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(req.body.password, process.env.PASS_SEC).toString(),
    });

    try {
      const savedUser = await newUser.save();
      res.status(201).json(savedUser);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});

//LOGIN

router.post("/login", async (req,res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username});
    !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!")

    const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      user.password,
      process.env.PASS_SEC
    );
    const OriginalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    OriginalPassword !== req.body.password && res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials");

    const accessToken = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: user._id,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SEC,
      {expiresIn: "3d"}
    );

    const { password, ...others} = user._doc;

    res.status(200).json({...others, accessToken});
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I apologize if this post is mostly code, I just don't know what else to say because I honestly don't know what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you `console.log(verifyToken)` or `verifyTokenAndAuthorization` you will get `undefined`

There's an issue with the way you created the `verifyTokenAndAuthorization` function and your `module.exports`. The `module.exports` should be outside of the `verifyToken` and the `verifyTokenAndAuthorization` function shouldn't be nested inside the `verifyToken` function.